# Gulp does not install

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have followed [these steps](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) on installing gulp.

For `node --version` I have `v6.8.0`.

For `npm --version` I have `v3.10.8`.

After that I write the command `npm install --global gulp-cli`, it installs a lot of things for a while, no error messages and after it finishes, when I try to write `gulp` or `gulp --version` I get this message:

```
gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ gulp --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: You should install `gulp`, not `gulp-cli`

Comment: do you have gulp already in `package.json`

Comment: @alexmac also installed like that, same error

Comment: @Danish I don't have it

Comment: i have posted my complete configuration below for you. Please check @salam

Answer (score 0):

check your `package.json` there should be `gulp` in `devDependencies` array.

See my `package.json` file as a example

```
{
  "name": "gulp-task",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some description of project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/danissh/gulp-task.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/danissh/gulp-task#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

and see my `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'));
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/styles/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css'], function() {});

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('assets/styles/**/*', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('assets/scripts/**/*', ['js']);

});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm this is where I have a package.json file. Is it the right one?

Comment: no this above `package.json` and `gulpfile.js` is specifically for your new project

Comment: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` contains `package.json` for installation fo nodejs. you should not touch that file i believe.

Comment: ok @salam i think what you need is to understand how project is create with gulp, please check this link https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-gulp-js

Comment: normally you can add my above `package.json` and `gulpfile.js` in your project but create directories like above config of my `gulpfile.js`